# Regex - Extract a substring of an email document with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to extract a substring of an email document with a regular expression. I'm testing the regex online, and it works perfectly:

[online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/BbWBPk/1)

I have a function to check the regex on Google Apps Script and the same regex isn't working here.

```
var regex = new RegExp("Intrusion signature\(s\)\:\n\n(.*)");
var e = regex.exec(data);
```

[Google Apps Script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL3HV.png)

[Logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJrfD.png)

Does anyone knows why is not working?

Comment: Maybe because `\n\n` isn't truly capturing all the spacing present between your expression and the text you want to extract. Try using `\s+` instead.

Comment: Also, when you're instantiating a `RegExp` object, backslashes must be escaped: `var regex = new RegExp("Intrusion signature\\(s\\)\\:\\n\\n(.*)");
`

Comment: I have changed the regex to Intrusion signature\(s\)\:\s+(.*) and still doesnt work... I think Google Apps Script does not accept this format :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using a literal regex instead of converting the string to a regex works.

```
var regex = new RegExp(/Intrusion signature\(s\)\:\n\n(.*)/);
```

[image]

Comment: I wrestled this problem for an hour, not understanding why my exec() was returning null, ahh the GAS documentation was not helping! Thanks so much!

Comment: @James D Nice, but how did you get the overview of all variables/objects? in a screen shot.
It looks handy ... easier then using a ` Logger.log `

Comment: @kris it's the debugger in the Rhyno script engine, you can use get it by inserting a breakpoint. Since the upgrade to V8 this is much more difficult and doesn't break properly the [issue has already been reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152948662)

Answer (score 1):

When you use regular strings with RegExp you need to escape every backslash.
Here are some alternatives you can use.
Another aspect to consider is that if you have CR+LF in your Spreasheet. In that case you need to change your code to include \r
I've added some google API mocked code so that the code snippet can run here

```js
// -----------------  Ignore this (Mock)
Logger=console;
class _SpreadsheetApp { getActiveSpreadsheet() {  class SpreadSheet {    getSheetByName(name) {
 class Sheet { getRange() { class Range { getValue() {
            return "  * Intrusion signature(s):\r\n\r\n      - This is the text I want to extract.\r\n\r\n * SI communication:\r\n";
} } return new Range(); } } return new Sheet(); } } return new SpreadSheet(); } }
var SpreadsheetApp=new _SpreadsheetApp();
// ----------------- Ignore this (Mock)

function checkRegExp() {
  var data=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LOG").getRange("C213").getValue();
  var regex = new RegExp("Intrusion signature\(s\)\:\n\n(.*)");  // ORIGINAL
  var e = regex.exec(data);
  Logger.log("Original:"+e);

  var sol1 = new RegExp("Intrusion signature\\(s\\)\\:\\r\\n\\r\\n(.*)");
  e = sol1.exec(data); 
  if (e) Logger.log("Solution 1:"+e[1]);

  var sol2 = new RegExp("Intrusion signature\\(s\\)\\:\\W{2,4}(.*)");
  e = sol2.exec(data); 
  if (e) Logger.log("Solution 2:"+e[1]);

  var sol3 = new RegExp("Intrusion signature\\(s\\)\\:(?:\\x0d\\x0a)+(.*)");
  e = sol3.exec(data); 
  if (e) Logger.log("Solution 3:"+e[1]);

  var sol4 =   new RegExp(/Intrusion signature\(s\)\:\r\n\r\n(.*)/);
  e = sol4.exec(data); 
  if (e) Logger.log("Solution 4:"+e[1]);
  
}

checkRegExp()
```